# Що означає слово "спирра"?

Tags: значення-слів

У творі "[Конотопська відьма](http://www.myslenedrevo.com.ua/uk/Lit/K/KvitkaOsnovjanenko/Prose/KonotopskaVidma/8.html)" Г. Квітки-Основ'яненка зутрів рядок:

> Уся спирра черніговська безумію удадеся!

Цікавить значення слова "спирра", бо у СУМі його немає, а якщо ввести в Гуглі словосполучення  "спирра чернігівська" або "чернігівська спирра", то він видає лише посилання на твір даного автора. Словник на сайті [Укрліт](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) також не дав ніяких результатів.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дивно, слово відмічене і підказка там *полк*. Навіть якщо так, то той самий осїдок [надає](http://www.myslenedrevo.com.ua/uk/Sci/Linguistics/RareWords/S2.html):

> Спирра (з грецьк.) – військова одиниця, рота

Грецьку погано знаю, але дивно, що 2 **р**, бо, гадаю, це воно: [**σπεῖρα**](//el.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%83%CF%80%CE%B5%E1%BF%96%CF%81%CE%B1#%CE%91%CF%81%CF%87%CE%B1%CE%AF%CE%B1_%CE%B5%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%B7%CE%BD%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AC_(grc))

> 5. *(στρατιωτικός όρος)* στρατιωτικό σώμα διακοσίων ανδρών (δύο εκατονταρχίες, διλοχία)
>      συνώνυμα: λατινικά manipulus
> 6. *(στρατιωτικός όρος)* στρατιωτική μονάδα σαν την κοόρτη
>      συνώνυμα: λατινικά cohors
>
> ---
>
> [biblehub](//biblehub.com/greek/4686.htm)
>
> Transliteration: speira
>   Phonetic Spelling: (spi'-rah)
>   Definition: a cohort, the tenth part of a legion; a military guard.
>
> ---
>
> [wiktionary](//el.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%83%CF%80%CE%B5%CE%AF%CF%81%CE%B1)
>
> *(figuratively)* band, cabal, gang

Тут деякі слова легко впізнають ся:

- συνώνυμα — синонімо
- λατινικά — латініка

Отже маємо:

- manipulus — [маніпула](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0) ~ 60-120 бійцїв;
- [cohors](/a/4427/585) — [когорта](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0) ~ 300–800 бійцїв.

Що теж є [*полком*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA) чи [*ротою*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_(%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%8F)) (80-150 бійцїв). Не знаю яким чином автор добирав слово (за змістом сходить ся), можливо за смаком звуку чи все-таки зважав на кількість. Гадаю, тут скоріш є *маніпула* — *рота*. Чому? Бо початок твору має:

> Смутний і невеселий стояв, руки зложивши, хваброї Конотопської *сотні* пан *сотник*…

[*Сотня*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8F) майже тотожнє *роти*.